# DPE problem invlolving Fourier transforms / partial eq.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series, transformation, partial-fractions

[image]

Don't even know where to start with this question! would really appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Do you know how to use the [method of characteristics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics)?

Comment: not confidently really

Comment: Try and follow the guide in the wikipedia page. If you are still struggling afterward, post a comment below and I'll help you.